# how to format the date in xslt to get expected output?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

could ou please tell me how to format date in xslt ..I am getting date in this format
`19 Jan, 2017 , 12.06PM IST`
here is my code

http://xsltransform.net/bFWR5Ey

how to convert string in xslt to get exoected output 
But expected out put
**Jan 19, 2017 , 12.06PM IST**

```
    <xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select ='a'/>
    </xsl:template>
```

xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<a>19 Jan, 2017 , 12.06PM IST</a>
```

Comment: If you're using XSLT 2.0, don't tag your questions with the `xslt-1.0` tag. And there is no grouping problem here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to swap the day and month, you could use the `replace` function with a regular expression.

Try this...

```
<xsl:value-of select ="replace(a, '^(\d{1,}) (\w{3,}),(.*)$', '$2 $1,$3')" />
```